# UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed method missing in API Version46

Tags: api

Our team had met a problem that when we update the API version to 46, the UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed method seems missing.
We have reported an issue on the developer forums.
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9062I000000IJlFQAW

And I'd like to post it here to see whether or not other guys face the same issue with us.

Thansk

Comment: I posted a tweet asking about this. It's not in the release notes, but the error is specific enough that I suspect it is intentional, not a bug. I'll circle around when/if I get an answer.

Comment: Is it fixed already? I tried it today and I think it is working now, no longer receiving the error.

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround to this problem, write yourselves a utility Apex class pinned at version 45 and with a BIG comment saying don't increase the version, and use this utility class method to access this functionality where you need to in your code base.