# UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed method is missing

Tags: apex, api

In API 45 we can use UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed method, but when update to API 46 show this method is missing. I can't found any information for that.

I found link: [UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed method missing in API Version46](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/266456/userinfo-iscurrentuserlicensed-method-missing-in-api-version46) looks like same issue with me but still don't know how to resolved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you have a small utility class left as API45 and call it from your other classes?

Comment: Sorry for delay, yes you're right, after upgrade API version it's work fine.