# Method was removed after version 45.0: isCurrentUserLicensed

Tags: apex, summer19

When I try to use [`UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm#apex_System_UserInfo_isCurrentUserLicensed) method, it shows an error `Method was removed after version 45.0: isCurrentUserLicensed`.
If I change the API version of the class to v45 it works fine.

Is there a replacement for this method in v46?

Couldn't find any mention in [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/search?query=isCurrentUserLicensed&version=summer19).

The code that gives an error when saved as v46,

```
public Class foo {
    public Boolean bar(String license){
        return UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed(license);
    }
}
```

[image: error]

The same code that is saved as v45

[image: non-error]

Comment: This was already raised in [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/266456/userinfo-iscurrentuserlicensed-method-missing-in-api-version46). There's no answer yet.

Comment: @PhilW Thank you! SE search didn't give me that result when I [searched for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIfL4.png). if anyone close vote this one as a duplicate of that, I would happily mark this.